# What is the name of the diagram in the picture?

Tags: architecture, diagram

I drew a diagram of the main components of the information system. What is this diagram called or most similar to it?
For example, there is a UML, a context diagram, a deployment diagram.
[image]

Comment: Most probably it is just a drawing and nothing more... At least the components should be on the same abstraction level. (For example: `API` and `RabbitMQ` are not on the same level ...). If you want to draw something more unified then please choose multiple [structural diagrams](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/uml-diagram-types-examples/) to visualize your system from different perspectives.